# Divs menores sobreposta em outra DIV

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando criar uma `DIV` com uma imagem de background e em cima dessa imagem preciso posicionar outras `DIVs`. Posicionei essas `DIVs` que ficaram por cima, mas ao redimensionar a tela a posição dessa `DIVs`, não se mantem no mesmo lugar.

Segue código

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%;}
            .bgFundoGame{
                background-image: url("fundo_game.png");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-size: cover;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: auto;
            }
            .pointGame{
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: #0f6ab4;
                border-radius: 50%;
                position: relative;
                top: 62%;
                left: 6.7%;
            }
            .bgFundoGame .pointGame:nth-child(2){
                position: relative;
                top: 34%;
                left: 5.1%;
                background-color: red;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bgFundoGame">
            <div class="pointGame"></div>
            <div class="pointGame"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, poste seu código